# cant format datetime using dataformatstring

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, date, dataformat

For some reason i can not format the text of my date in a gridview

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="deptdate" HeaderText="Departure Date" dataformatstring="{0:ddd, MM/d/yyyy}" htmlencode="False" SortExpression="deptdate" />

I still get this:

May 10 2011 12:00AM
```

**I DID NOT SET MY FIELD TO DATETIME IN THE DATABASE...DOY**

Comment: Can you post your dataformatstring code?  Or any other code pertinent to this?  It's a bit difficult to give you a solid answer without.  Also, what result are you trying to get?

Comment: sorry i didnt realize my code didnt show up in my post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried this approach?

http://peterkellner.net/2006/05/24/how-to-set-a-date-format-in-gridview-using-aspnet-20using-htmlencode-property/

```
<asp id="GridView1" runat="server" :GridView>
<columns>
  <asp headertext="CreationDate" dataformatstring="{0:M-dd-yyyy}" 
       datafield="CreationDate" :BoundField HtmlEncode="false" />
</columns>
```

Comment: @Paul - then you can simply write dataformatstring="{0:dd-M-yyyy}" instead

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DataFormatString="{0:d}"` for short date format in your column definition.

Answer (score 0):

Since Q2 2013 the RadHtmlChart can be databound to DateTime objects, so that XAxis Labels, Series Labels and ToolTips can be formatted to the desired date format. More information on formatting dates is available in Date Axis article: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart-date-axis.html