# Dropdownlist date format

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am using a DataTable to populate a dropdownlist on my web form, as well as using a stored procedure to query the database.  The list retrieves only one field from the database and will be used in conjunction with a gridview to view all reservations made on a specific date.

Everything works fine, except for the format of the date.  Right now it is showing the date as well as hours, minutes, and seconds. I have tried using the DataFormatString property the the web form but no luck.

Webform:

```
  <b>Please select a date:</b>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDateSelection" runat="server" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"></asp:DropDownList>
  <br />
  <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" CssClass="validate"></asp:Label>
```

code behind used to query database:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    loadDates();
}

protected void loadDates()
{
  DataTable dates = new DataTable();

  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBAccess.GetConnectionString()))
  {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_sel_ReservationDates", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    try
    {
      SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
      adapter.Fill(dates);
      ddlDateSelection.DataSource = dates;
      ddlDateSelection.DataTextField = "ReservationDate";
      ddlDateSelection.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      lblError.Text = "Something bad has happened.  Please try again.<br />Message: " + ex;
    }
  }
  ddlDateSelection.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Select", "0"));
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as this is a learning project for myself. Thanks

Comment: repeat question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357582/how-to-fix-date-format-in-asp-net-boundfield-dataformatstring

Comment: It looks like you want the short date format, try changing your DataFormatString to simply "{0:d}".

Comment: Sjramsay - those are properties of a boundfield, not a dropdownlist...

Comment: Evets Rezik - I tried that solution, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need to refer to the correct property

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDateSelection" runat="server" 
                   DataTextFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

[DropDownList properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your SQL code to return only date

```
SELECT CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE())
```

> RESULT: 2013-07-14